# return queries result like two cols

Tags: sql

I have these two queries,

```
SELECT date(d1.date) AS date, d3.country_name AS country_name, COUNT(*) AS male
FROM f1
INNER JOIN d1 ON f1.id_start_date = d1.id_start_date
INNER JOIN d2 ON f1.id_end_date = d2.id_end_date
INNER JOIN d3 ON f1.id_user = d3.id_user AND d3.gender = 'M'
GROUP BY date, country_name
ORDER BY country_name

SELECT date(d1.date) AS date, d3.country_name AS country_name, COUNT(*) AS female
FROM f1
INNER JOIN d1 ON f1.id_start_date = d1.id_start_date
INNER JOIN d2 ON f1.id_end_date = d2.id_end_date
INNER JOIN d3 ON f1.id_user = d3.id_user AND d3.gender = 'F'
GROUP BY date, country_name
ORDER BY country_name
```

that return me something like this:

```
date, country, male
2009-01-01, Spain, 34
```

and

```
date, country, female
2009-01-01, Spain, 12
```

but I need a query that return me this:

```
date, country, male, female
2009-01-01, Spain, 34, 12
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result in separate columns:

```
SELECT 
    date(d1.date) AS date, 
    d3.country_name AS country_name, 
    sum(case when d3.gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) AS male,
    sum(case when d3.gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) AS female
FROM f1
INNER JOIN d1 
    ON f1.id_start_date = d1.id_start_date
INNER JOIN d2 
    ON f1.id_end_date = d2.id_end_date
INNER JOIN d3 
    ON f1.id_user = d3.id_user 
GROUP BY date, country_name
ORDER BY country_name
```